# (opengl) why i can draw with glVertex3f but not with glDrawElements?

Tags: opengl, graphics, vertex

Assume that everything else functions, if I do:

```
glcolor3f(1.f,1.f,1.f);
glBegin(GL_POLYGON);
glVertex3f(100.0, 100.0, 0.0);
glVertex3f(100.0, 600.0, 0.0);
glVertex3f(600.0, 600.0, 0.0);
glVertex3f(600.0, 100.0, 0.0);
glEnd();
```

I can safely draw, but if I make through this nothing appears:

```
glEnableClientState(GL_COLOR_ARRAY);
glEnableClientState(GL_VERTEX_ARRAY);
glEnableClientState(GL_NORMAL_ARRAY);
GLfloat vertici[] =
{
    100.0, 100.0, 0.0,
    100.0, 600.0, 0.0,
    600.0, 600.0, 0.0,
    600.0, 100.0, 0.0
};

GLfloat colori[] =
{
    0.0, 1.0, 0.0,
    1.0, 0.0, 0.0,
    0.0, 0.0, 1.0,
    1.0, 1.0, 0.0

};

GLfloat normali[] =
{
    0.0, 0.0, 1.0,
    0.0, 0.0, 1.0,
    0.0, 0.0, 1.0,
    0.0, 0.0, 1.0

};

GLbyte indici[] =
{
    0, 1, 2, 3
};

glVertexPointer(3, GL_FLOAT, 0, vertici);//dichiarativa
glColorPointer(3, GL_FLOAT, 0, colori);
glNormalPointer(GL_FLOAT, 0, normali);
glDrawElements(GL_POLYGON, 4, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, indici);//disegnante

glDisableClientState(GL_NORMAL_ARRAY);
glDisableClientState(GL_VERTEX_ARRAY);
glDisableClientState(GL_COLOR_ARRAY);
```

What's wrong? What do I need to activate? I forgot what what? I made mistakes?
I use SDL, glut, glew.

Comment: Those two examples are far from the same vertices; the first one applies the color 1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f to each vertex. Also, you are telling OpenGL to use an unsigned type but storing the indices in `GLbyte` (which is signed). You are not using any negative or excessively large unsigned numbers so it should not be _too_ big a deal, but you should always match `GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE` with `GLubyte`. Having said that, most GPUs do not even support 8-bit indices in hardware - `GL_UNSIGNED_SHORT` is the smallest native index format.

Comment: Assume that everything else functions this means that I made a glOrtho to change the scale!